# view as html feature

Tags: php, linux, apache

can anyone help me how to read .doc and .xsl file on linux server through php like the view as html feature on gmail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this library to read Excel and gave me very good result, I owe it to word
[Read Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)